# Why my subject observable subscriber is calling multiple times in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In angular i have a service like this

```
  private subject = new Subject<any>();
  private  vehicleSubject = new Subject<any>();

  sendData = (data: any) => this.subject.next({ data });

  sendVehicleData = (data: any) => this.vehicleSubject.next({ data });

  getData = (): Observable<any> => this.subject.asObservable();

  getVehicleData = (): Observable<any> => this.vehicleSubject.asObservable();
```

Now i have my `sidebar(parent)` component like this with `tab view` both of `primeng` in my `sidebar.component.html`

{{user?.fullName}}

Services & Inspections</h3> -->
                
            
        
        
            
                Inspection works</h3> -->

in my `sidebar.component.ts` when `sidebar` is opened and user click on outside of `sidebar` so i will pas data to my child component like this

```
  onSidebarOutside(e) {
   if (this.index === 0 && this.sideBarVisible && 
     !this.isCustomerCancelBtnClicked) {
     e.target.value = true;
     this.verifyCustomer = e;
  } else if(this.index === 1){
      console.log('in index 1');
      this.dataService.sendVehicleData(true);
  }
  if (this.isCustomerCancelBtnClicked) {
    this.isCustomerCancelBtnClicked = false;
   }
  }
```

Inside my `vehicle-side-list.component` i have a subscriber in `ngOnInit` to get data like this

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.dataService.getVehicleData().subscribe(obj => {
     console.log('in vehicle item subscruber', obj);
    });
}
```

but problem is this that subscriber inside my `vehicle-side-list.component` called multiple times and i got this log `console.log('in vehicle item subscruber', obj);` multiple times. I am noet getting that why is it calling multiple times. I am sending value only once and by sending value from `sidebar` component it is calling multiple times.

My component calling structure is like this

```
sidebar
  -customer-component
    -appointment-component
  -vehicle-component
    -appointment-component
  -inspection-component
    -appointment-component
```

And i want to pass data from `sidebar` to `appointment-component`

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: I am thinking that you have memory leak. You are subscribing to that Observable many times and you don't unsubscribe. Give it a test, refresh the website and check the functionality. The issue will happen only if you navigate between pages and the subscribe happens multiple times.

Comment: @ahsan Did you find any solution for this? i am also facing similar issue and i am blocked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you have not unsubscribed the observable inside ngDestroy method.

Whenever you are clicking you are adding new component which is adding more listeners to that observable. Just unsubscribe the observable in ngDestroy of child component and it should work.

You need following changes in child component. Create a private property and use it to unsubscribe.

```
private destroy:Subject = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
   this.dataService.getVehicleData().pipe(
     takeUntil(this.destroy)     // import takeUntil from rxjs/operators.
      ).subscribe(obj => {
     console.log('in vehicle item subscruber', obj);
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroy.next();
}
```

[post edited]

Comment: I am not adding new component on clicking. Basically i have `sidebar` as my parent component and in that `sidebar` i have tab view and in each `tab` there is a separate component is calling you can see in my `sidebar.component.html`. I am passing data to my child component only when user is on the tab and click outside of the sidebar. So i am sending data only once but subscriber in my child component calls multiple times

Comment: Are you doing unsubscribing inside the vehicle-side-list.component.ts? I am assuming it is not happening. Does it console multiple times when you click outside the sidebar for first time? I don't think so, It must be happening from second time click outside the sidebar. Please tell?

Comment: I implemented your solution in the way you mentioned. But now the issue is happening that when on first time i click outside of `sidebar` so `subscriber` inside my `vehicle-side-list` component is not calling. And yes i am unsubscribing in my `vehicle-side-list` component. Please not that i have multiple tabs in my sidebar. I just showed my one tab in my question post. And you know that  when tab is switched so component will not destroy.

Comment: can you suggest me a very simple way of sharing data from parent component to child component with observable and without Input?

Comment: If you want to pass data from parent to children without Input then you have to use a share service, is it fine? Can you give more context of your code? Do we have same component for every tab?

Comment: Basically i have `sidebar` my parent component and in `sidebar` i have 4 tabs. And in each tab i am calling separate component. Like in tab1 i am calling component1, in tab2  i am calling component2 like so on. And inside my each tab's component i am calling another common component which is calling in each tab's component. And i want to pass data from `sidebar` to that common component.

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a stackblitz instance? Else please post your complete parent HTML and TScode.

Comment: i have updated my complete Html of `sidebar` component and i also updated the `function` code which is calling when i click outside of `sidebar` and pass data to my `child` component.

Comment: The issue is with unsubscribing inside child components. Subject multicast their values, whenever you are call next method it send values all the listeners subscribed upto that point. You need to unsubscribe the observables inside all children components.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211851/discussion-between-ahsan-and-prince).

Comment: @JasdeepSingh Could  you please provide solution for this question? I have mutiple tabs in same routing. my subscriber is called n times if n tabs are open.

Comment: @ahsan please let me know if we can connect on this, if you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the memory leak caused by the subject observable. You can simple solve this by unsubscribing it on ngOnDestroy. It is good practice to unsubscribe the subjects and behavior subject on component destroying to avoid unexpected results.

```
vehicleDataRef !:Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.vehicleDataRef = this.dataService.getVehicleData().subscribe(obj => {
    console.log('in vehicle item subscruber', obj);
    });
   }
    
   ngOnDestroy() {
    this.vehicleDataRef.unsubscribe();
   }
```